# Stub object function which resolves with a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I'm trying to use sinon to stub the `save` method in this object

```
const db = {
  user: {
    findOne: () => Promise.resolve({
      id: '43214321-4321-4321-4321-432143214321',
      save: () => Promise.resolve({ // I WANTED TO STUB THIS METHOD
        id: '43214321-4321-4321-4321-432143214321'
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Via this

```
beforeEach(() => {
  sinon.stub(db.user.findOne, 'save').rejects()
})
```

And I'm getting this error

```
 TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property save
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const saveStub = sinon.stub().resolves();`

const findOneObject = {
      save: saveStub
};

sinon.stub(db.user, 'findOne').returns(findOneStub);
```

You can add the `id`  stub if needed

Comment: almost, OP is stubbing `save` to reject and `findOne` needs to return a `Promise`

Comment: We could just make the `findOneObject` to be `sinon.stub().resolves({
      save: saveStub
})`

Answer (score 0):

`findOne` resolves to a new object each time it is called so there isn't a way to stub `save` without also stubbing `findOne`:

```js
const saveStub = sinon.stub().rejects();
sinon.stub(db.user, 'findOne').resolves({
  id: '43214321-4321-4321-4321-432143214321',
  save: saveStub
});
```